# Error creating aggregate materialized view

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, materialized-view

Trying to create an aggregate materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_LLATTRDATA_MAX_VERSIONS
    NOLOGGING
    BUILD IMMEDIATE 
    REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
    ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
    AS 
        SELECT AD.DEFID, AD.ATTRID, MAX(AD.VERNUM) AS MAX_VERNUM, MIN(AD.DEFVERN) AS MAX_DEFVERN
        FROM   CSTST.MV_LLATTRDATA_PARTITIONED_TEST AD, DTREECORE DT
        WHERE AD.ID = DT.DATAID
        GROUP BY AD.DEFID, AD.ATTRID;
```

I get this error however:

> ORA-23413: table "CSTST"."DTREECORE" does not have a materialized view
>   log
>   23413. 00000 -  "table \"%s\".\"%s\" does not have a materialized view log"
>   *Cause:    The fast refresh can not be performed because the master table
>              does not contain a materialized view log.
>   *Action:   Use the CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG command to create a
>              materialized view log on the master table.

I've created `Materialized View Logs on (LLATTRDATA and DTREECORE) WITH ROWID INCLUDING NEW VALUES;`

But I still get the error and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Can you please share the script used to create materialized view logs?